# How to get Pandas to stop automatically sorting column titles in new DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to build a Pandas DataFrame based on repeated API calls. I have filtered the JSON response object (which contains more data than I need) into several dicts. When I merge the dicts (using `python new_dict = {**old_dict1, **old_dict2}`) the order of keys is preserved. However, when I create a blank dataframe and use the append argument, the resulting dataframe sorts the column names (formerly dict keys) alphabetically even when the sort parameter is false. I would like to preserve the original order

Here is an example row of the dataframe I am hoping to create:

```py
detection_dict={'blacklist_detections': 0,'detection_rate':'0%'}
geo_dict={'continent': 'North America','country':'United States','region':'Alabama'}
anon_dict = {'is_proxy': False,'is_webproxy': False,'is_vpn': False,'is_hosting': False,'is_tor': False}

combo_dict = {**detection_dict, **geo_dict, **anon_dict}
```

calling combo_dict returns:

```py
{'blacklist_detections': 0,
 'detection_rate': '0%',
 'continent': 'North America',
 'country': 'United States',
 'region': 'Alabama',
 'is_proxy': False,
 'is_webproxy': False,
 'is_vpn': False,
 'is_hosting': False,
 'is_tor': False}
```

Which is the order I want these keys to remain in. However, calling

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(combo_dict, ignore_index = True, sort = False)
```

returns a dataframe with all keys sorted in alphabetical order (blacklist_detections, continent, country, detection_rate, etc.)

I am unsure whether the way I am adding each row to the dataframe or the way that I am merging the dicts is responsible for this behavior, but I would like it to remain unsorted. I do not understand why sort=False is not doing anything for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it sorts the columns in the way you're doing it is because you're starting with an empty DataFrame. Based on the [df.append() code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L6984-L7124) pandas checks for the difference between the columns in the existing df and the appended rows using [`pandas.index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and by default will sort the columns, since none of these columns exist in the empty df.

If for some reason you *need* to start with an empty DataFrame, rather than the other alternatives in the answers above, then you can always do this:

```
combo_cols = list(combo_dict) # get the current order of the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=combo_cols) # set empty df columns to match 
df.append(combo_dict, ignore_index = True, sort = False) # append the dataframes
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I figured it had something to do with starting from a blank df or .append() but I couldn't quite connect the dots.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a dict of dicts that you provided and then utilized `pd.Dataframe.from_dict()` to generate a dataframe. Check if this results in your desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

api_data = {'detection_dict' : {'blacklist_detections': 0,'detection_rate':'0%'},
            'geo_dict' : {'continent': 'North America','country':'United States','region':'Alabama'},
            'anon_dict' : {'is_proxy': False,'is_webproxy': False,'is_vpn': False,'is_hosting': False,'is_tor': False}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(api_data)
df

------
                     detection_dict geo_dict        anon_dict
blacklist_detections 0              NaN             NaN
continent            NaN            North America   NaN
country              NaN            United States   NaN
detection_rate       0              NaN             NaN
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try df=pd.DataFrame(combo_dict,index=[0]). 
It shall return an unsorted data frame similar to the combo_dict dictionary.

[image]